# Spring 4 and thymeleaf form validatation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Can anyone give sample Java code for validating the HTML form (ex: form attributes not null, minimum and maximum size) using via Spring MVC and with thymeleaf-spring4 libraries?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#validation-and-error-messages

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, you annotate your `dao` object (in this case user), with the constraints you need:

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String login;

    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;

    @Min(18)
    private int age;
}
```

These annotation are from `javax.validation.constraints`.

After this you need to modify your controller, you need to clarify your controller that the object must be `@Valid`:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@Valid final User user, final BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }

    // Your code
    return "redirect:/userList";
}
```

The errors are stored in the `BindingResult`.

Finally show the errors:

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('login')}" th:errors="*{login}"></span>
```

**Edit:**

Return `ModelAndView`

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(@Valid final User user, final BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form");
        mav.addObject(bindingResult);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

These are latest maven dependencies for java validation API

1.dependency
**groupId** javax.validation
**artifactId** validation-api
**version** 1.1.0.Final

2.dependency
**groupId** org.hibernate
**artifactId** hibernate-validator
**version** 5.0.1.Final

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and may i know maven dependency for javax.validation.constraints ?

Comment: Hi Manu, Thanx for it. May I know above controller method return String, So then how to map this String to My ModelView Object. Basically It means, My registration submit button has form action and it will hit to Controller Method and it return ModelView Object directly.

Comment: then you easily adding the `bindingResult` to the `ModelAndView`-Object

Comment: These are latest dependencies for java validation API

Comment: could you fix your problem?

Comment: Ya Manu, Thax Your Guide :)

Comment: please accept this as the correct answer for other user there searching for similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

1. First, comes the Object...

   ```
   public class PruebaFormCommand {

   @NotEmpty
   @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
   private String textoPrueba;

   public String getTextoPrueba() {
       return textoPrueba;
   }

   public void setTextoPrueba(String textoPrueba) {
       this.textoPrueba = textoPrueba;
   }

   }
   ```
2. Then, the Controller:

   ```
   @Controller
   public class PruebaFormController {

   @RequestMapping("/pruebaform")
   public String pruebaForm(Model model){

       model.addAttribute("pruebaFormCommand", new PruebaFormCommand());

       return "pruebaform";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/dopruebaform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String doPruebaForm(@Valid PruebaFormCommand pruebaFormCommand, BindingResult bindingResult){

       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           return "pruebaform";
       }

       return "pruebaformcomplete";

   }

   }
   ```
3. Then, the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
          th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>

    <script src="../static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
            th:src="@{/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js}"></script>

    <link th:href="@{/css/custom.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <title>Checkout</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>PRUEBA Form</h2>

    <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${pruebaFormCommand}" th:action="@{/dopruebaform}" method="post">

        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p th:text="#{pruebaFormCommand.hasErrors}">Error Message</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('textoPrueba')} ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Meteme algo payo:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{textoPrueba}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>

                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('textoPrueba')}">
                       <ul>
                           <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('textoPrueba')}" th:text="${err}" />
                       </ul>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Finally, include your message.properties:

> pruebaFormCommand.hasErrors=Porfa corrige los errores:
>   NotEmpty.pruebaFormCommand.textoPrueba={0} caracteres mínimo....
>   Size.pruebaFormCommand.textoPrueba={0} debe tener entre {2} y {1} caracteres